# Pusher is not catching the triggered event since there is a change of TLS from september 6, 2018 in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, tls1.2, pusher, tls1.0

Pusher is not catching the triggered event since there is a change of TLS from September 6, 2018.
It not giving a single error on console, when I open the page that contains the client side JavaScript of pusher it shows that channels are connected to the pusher server but when I trigger any of it It doesn't responds neither gives any error. Simply its not calling the bind event callback at all.
Here is the minified pusher.js that I included.

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.3/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the client side JS binded event code.

```
var notificationsWrapper   = $('.dropdown-notifications');
var notificationsToggle    = notificationsWrapper.find('a[data-toggle]');
var notificationsCountElem = notificationsToggle.find('i[data-count]');
var notificationsCount     = parseInt(notificationsCountElem.data('count'));
var notifications          = notificationsWrapper.find('ul.dropdown-menu');

if (notificationsCount <= 0) {
  notificationsWrapper.hide();
}

// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;
var pusher = new Pusher('AppKey', {
  cluster: 'ap2',
  forceTLS: true
});
// Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
var channel = pusher.subscribe('subscribed');
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    console.log('subscribed successful') ;
});
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function(status) {
    console.log('subscribed error: '+ status) ;
});
channel.bind('theEvent', function(data) {
  var existingNotifications = notifications.html();
  var avatar = Math.floor(Math.random() * (71 - 20 + 1)) + 20;
  var newNotificationHtml = `
    <li class="notification active">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <div class="media-object">
              <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/71/`+avatar+`.png" class="img-circle" alt="50x50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <strong class="notification-title">`+data.type+`</strong>
            <!--p class="notification-desc">Extra description can go here</p-->
            <div class="notification-meta">
              <small class="timestamp">`+data.date_time+`</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
  `;
  notifications.html(newNotificationHtml + existingNotifications);
  notificationsCount += 1;
  notificationsCountElem.attr('data-count', notificationsCount);
  notificationsWrapper.find('.notif-count').text(notificationsCount);
  notificationsWrapper.show();

  $.playSound('/notification/notification.mp3') ;
});
```

This is where I call the trigger in laravel controller.

```
        $pusher = HomeController::getPusher() ;
        $pusher->trigger('subscribed', 'theEvent', $callBack);
```

These two lines are in a function that is called if a specific route is called and executed before controller respond with view. and the Pusher instance is created with the reference of Home Controller. and these both route function and below the pusher function is in Home Controller.

```
public function getPusher() {
    $options = array(
        'cluster' => 'ap2',
        'useTLS' => true
      );
      $pusher = new Pusher(
        'AppKey',
        'AppSecret',
        'AppId',
        $options
      );

    return $pusher ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same issue if you just continue using the `encrypted:true` as I assume you were doing before?

I help maintain this library and will investigate this. In the meantime there have been no changes in our infrastructure relating to TLS yet - this change was just a variable rename. In the meantime you can use an older version of the library to avoid it. I'll get back to you as soon as I can!

Comment: Nope, it was working fine. Today when i started working i faced this issue and then i saw the pop up on pusher website of removing tls1.0 and also saw that the parameter encrypted is change to forceTLS in cliemt side and useTLS at backend, i changed it and its still not working in both cases.

Comment: I tried to use the older version, its not working either. If you can provide me any link where i can cross check whether i am using a valid older version, that will be appreciated for now. And i am looking forward for this issue to be resolved ASAP.

Comment: pusher-http-php v3.1.1 and older will be fine for the server, and for PusherJS and version v4.2.2 or below will be fine.

Comment: I used these versions that you mentioned also the olders too, still not working.at chrome console pusher prints that all are connected and prints the success channel console value and after some time it also do the stuff like "ping pong" too but not detecting the event

Comment: @TahaSiddiqui How are you sir have you solved the problem because I am facing the same exact problem ?!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Kevin, I you told me to try older version and it worked for me. I am sorry I got late in replying.
When you told me to use the older versions it was not working either But with a little update of timestamp from internet time in PC settings it worked. I don't really know why it was not working in any of the laptop/desktops at the same time.